# VUEJS SSR, how to?

Tags: vue.js, seo, server-side-rendering

I made a VueJS 3 app (WebPack 3.12.0), with prerendering (not serverside), and the content of some page are loaded via ajax request, so google bots can't see the text (this is the problem here).

I read that I need to use SSR to do this. So I tried a couple of tutorials but no one seem to works (some do nothing, others crashes my app). I don't really know which one is the best and they are all using differents solutions.

First of all, do I need to use SSR to achieve what I want ? And if yes, anyone have a good tutorial (and a working one) ?

Thanks guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for SSR with Vue is to use Nuxt.js: https://nuxtjs.org/

It's not that complex, working really great !
It will probably be migrated to Vue3 really soon (Nuxt 2.15.2 is using Vue2 still), maybe even today during the [JS World Conference](https://frontenddeveloperlove.com/program#d-5-s-7__).

Also, you can check those videos of Debbie who does a nice job of explaining things in a clear and simple way: https://www.youtube.com/c/DebbieOBrien/videos

Comment: thanks for your quick answer ! So I need to redo all my app using nuxt ?

Comment: It can be as easy as to copy pasta some files depending of the size of the app. But yeah, Nuxt is probably one of the most flexible you could use as of right now because it will handle various SSR lifecycles, hooks during the loading of the page and so on, which will indeed require a rewrite on some parts if you want to benefit from it. But it's also a structure that you can follow and some neat helpers/features that will make your life easier, especially for SSR. Nuxt is just a layer on top of Vue.

Comment: And there is no way to not redo all my app ? Looking at how nuxt work I'll need to redo really a lot of things

Comment: If you want a really solid foundation and clean structure, you will need to redo it yeah. The SSR pretty much needs to be thought at the start of the project too, maybe you did not have the info about it when you started but this kind of stuff is always tricky to just switch to in a few clicks. Also, what is the things that may be a challenge for you while trasitionning to nuxt ?

Comment: A lot of things lol , router, passing props, template, structure, ... a lot of things are totally different. I love how vuejs documentation don't talk about the server side rendering problem at all in "get started" or "why use vuejs". 

So ok thanks, I can say goodbye to the weekend ^^ Thank's for your help mate !

Comment: Router will be a bit of a change yeah, but it's essentially less complex and pretty much as configurable if needed. Passing props is the same. Template is the same too, you can add some `layouts` to it also. You can make a clunky working example and refine it in the mid-term. But yeah, I get your point that you're not warned in advance by the Vue docs that SSR is a thing to consider early on. It's actually pretty down in the docs yeah: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html#Nuxt-js Still, yeah busy week-end I guess, glad I could help ! :)